# Accessing values of JSON object

Tags: php, javascript, json

Hy all, i have problems with accessing values from JSON object.

First i do `json_encode($something)` where "something" is result from query to DB.
(precisely 3 rows). Then in .js i did following: `var data = ?php echo $something; ?>;`

I tested in firebug and data is(i will show 1 row):

```
[Object {x="something1", y="something2", z="10", w="20"}, ...] so i get Array of objects.
```

Now i need to access these values but i will not know their names nor their count, so i can't use something like `console.log(data[0].x)` which work fine and output is "something1";

When i try a little more generic way to do this like:

```
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    for(var prop in data[i]) {
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
        console.log(data[i].prop);                  
    }
}
```

I get "undefined" for each value.
How to solve this. Thanks.

Comment: http://json.org/ / http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is because of this line

console.log(data[i].**prop**);

Beacause of the dot notation, It expects the object to have the **prop key** and not the `value of prop`

Try this instead **(Use bracket notation instead)**

```
console.log(data[i][prop]);
// This make sure that it will first fetch the value 
//of propertyName and then search for the key on it
```

**Square bracket notation allows access to properties containing special characters and selection of properties using variables**

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/PSJpY/)**

Comment: Just my mistake in copy-paste, it is(data[i].prop) i edited.
(Results are undefined), any suggestion?

Comment: Lol, thanks it works like a charm i forget to try with [] notation.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the loops with something like this:

```
<html>
<script>
var a = "[ {'x':'something1', 'y':'something2', 'z':'10', 'w':'20'}, {'a':'somethingA',         'b':'somethingB', 'c':'1', 'd':'2'}]";
var data = eval('(' + a + ')');
for(var i in data) {
for(var prop in data[i]) {
        console.log(data[i][prop]);                  
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```